# Kotlin App crashes when I try to navigate through BottomNavigation

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm competely new to Kotlin trying to build an app following a tutorial, but trying to navigate to fragment it completely crashes.

This what I got after I tried to navigate to the other fragment:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.application, PID: 10385
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f08005a (com.example.application:id/container) for fragment Create{b25f2a9 (ffc51d9a-d9bb-425d-a264-1a68c77134fb) id=0x7f08005a}
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:875)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

This how I try to navigate to  the fragment.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val bottomNavigation: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)



    }
    private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.menu_home -> {

                val fragment_main = Main.newInstance()
                openFragment(fragment_main)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.menu_create -> {

                val fragment_create = Create.newInstance()
                openFragment(fragment_create)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.menu_your -> {

                val fragment_your_articles = YourArticles.newInstance()
                openFragment(fragment_your_articles)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }




    private fun openFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment)
        transaction.addToBackStack(null)
        transaction.commit()
    }


}
```

One of the  Fragment class

```
class Create : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? =
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create, container, false)

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): Create = Create()
    }

}
```

I want to know what mistake did I made to cause the crash and how can I fix it.

This xml file of one of the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView4"
       android:layout_width="100dp"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
       android:text="@string/create_screen"
       />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said I'm completely new to Kotlin and I'm still getting used to how and what must be displayed if I'm trying to use Fragment. I forgot that I need `FrameLayout` to my `main_activity.xml`

As I added `FrameLayout` in my `main_activity.xml` file it's started working as I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The id passed into FragmentTransaction.add(), in your case `R.id.fragment_create`, must be a child of the layout specified in `setContentView()`.

For help: A view is a child of another view if it is declared inside of the parent view in the XML. ie. a `TextView` inside of a `RelativeLayout` is a child of the `RelativeLayout`

Comment: In tutorial I noticed that it was used `LinearLayout`  instead of `RelativeLayout` . I updated the error and added xml file. Can you check again?

Answer (score 0):

This line in your `openFragment` function

```
transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment)
```

tells it to place the fragment in the ViewGroup with the ID "container". But your layout does not contain a ViewGroup with this ID. Check your `activity_main.xml` layout and make sure it has one with that ID.

Comment: If that's not the issue, then please add your activity layout to your question so we can see it.

Comment: Anyway I managed to find the error. I just needed to add Frame layout in Main_activity.xml file. As I said I'm completely new to Kotlin and Android Studio so i'm just getting used to on how Fragments should be displayed